# Setting path in Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I am setting up a cucumber scenario for setting up a valid user where my last step is:

"Then  I should be taken to the show user page"

which I define as:

```
Then /I should be taken to the show user page/ do
  @user = User.last
  if current_path.respond_to? :should
    current_path.should == path_to(user_path(@user))
  else
    assert_equal path_to(user_path(@user)), current_path
  end
  visit(user_path(@user))
end
```

After getting an error "Can't find mapping from "/users/49" to a path."  I attempted to define the path as:

```
when /^users\/(.+)$/ do |user|
  user_path(user.to_i)
end
```

But this yields the error:

syntax error, unexpected keyword_do, expecting keyword_then or ',' or ';' or '\n'
    when /^landlords/(.+)$/ do |landlord|

I am relatively new to rails and web development and completely new to cucumber and TDD.  Also new to regex.  Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `user_path(@user)` is giving you the path you need, so wrapping that in `path_to` is causing the error as it tries to do the same thing.

I think getting rid of the `path_to` call might help:

```
current_path.should == user_path(@user)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the "unexpected keyword_do" error is because you have **when** instead of **When**, i.e. Ruby is interpreting it as a *case*-style statement. But as Jon M points, you don't need that anyway.

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks for info.  It seems that the lower case when in the paths.rb file is part of the cucumber syntax.  Does that mean I shouldn't be using do blocks in the paths.rb file?